How to reroute stdout and stderr to a Frame element (i.e. not to a Multiline element)
This Multiline rerouting below works, but this is not matching what I exactly want:
output_layout = [   
        [sg.Text("OUTPUT")],
        [sg.Multiline(size=(0,5), font='Courier 8', text_color="#DBFF33",
        expand_x=True, expand_y=True, write_only=True, border_width=2,         
        reroute_stdout=True, reroute_stderr=True, echo_stdout_stderr=True,
        autoscroll=True, auto_refresh=True)]]

I checked similar questions and this documentation about the Frame parameters: I could not find any to reroute the standard output into the Frame element.
My current Frame element, "as is" without rerouting yet:
# output_layout = [
#     sg.Frame(title= frameTitles[12],font=FrameFontCol1, layout=[[sg.Column(cb12, 
#     size= (0 , size[1]) ) ]], expand_x=True)]
#     -> I tried to apply the stdout re-routing args here, but it does not "fly" obv.


Maybe this is not possible or, would there be kind of a clean workaround or embedding/nested solutions?

A Frame Element that contains other Elements, not contains text, so you need to find any element can show text to reroute stdout and stderr, most of time, Multiline will be the best one. For example, sg.Frame("Title", [[sg.Multiline("", reroute_stdout=True, reroute_stderr=True)]]).

@JasonYang thank you for the guidance, I'll try that way.

As advised in the comments, I could embed a MultiLine element into a Frame element, as follows :
output_layout = [ sg.Frame("OUTPUT",  
                [[sg.Multiline("", size=(int(size[0]/2),5),font='Courier 8', text_color="#DBFF33",
                    reroute_stdout=True, reroute_stderr=True,
                    echo_stdout_stderr=True, autoscroll=True, auto_refresh=True, )]], expand_x=True)
                ]

Hope it may help anyone.

would not be easier if you just collect the stdout and stderr in a variable and update it to the multiline element by key?
windows["-key_to_multiline-"].update(std_var)

maybe it is easier to debug too

Thx, yes it's a possible solution. Pls consider the question code is a summary case of a bigger code, so I can't apply for the proposed solution straight out of the box, unless a time-consuming integration work :-). Thx again, it may help.
